# Unexpected values from text input in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am making an app that takes input from a slider to create the matching number of input text boxes. However, when I print the values from the input boxes it does not always update.

Example:
Pick 3 on slider input. Put 1,2,3 into the 3 text boxes respectively.Hit submit. Prints number = 1 number = 2 number = 3. When I move the slider to 2 and hit enter, I get number = 1 number = 2 despite no values being in the text input anymore. If I move the slider to 4, I will than get the output number = NA number = NA number = 3 number = NA.

Clearly it is remembering previous input values, but I cannot understand why or how to fix it.

```
ui.R
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
  column(4, wellPanel(
    sliderInput("numObs", "Number of observations", 1, 30, 3),
    uiOutput("buttons"),
    submitButton(text = "Apply Changes", icon = NULL)
)),
column(8,
       textOutput("a")
)
```

)
))

```
server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$buttons <- renderUI({
    obs <- input$"numObs";
    objs <-list();
    for (i in 1:obs ){
      objs <- list(objs, numericInput(inputId = paste0("t", i), "Day:", NA),br());
    }        
  objs <- fluidRow(objs);
  })

  t<- function(){
    for(i in 1:input$"numObs"){
      if(i ==1){
        t <- c(as.numeric(input[[paste0("t",i)]])[1]);
      }
      else{
        t <- c(t,as.numeric(input[[paste0("t",i)]])[1]);
      }
    }
    return(t);
  }

  output$a<- renderText({
  paste("number = ", t());
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes and introduced a few things to your code. Its better to use `actionButton` than the `submitButton` as it is more flexible. If you dont like the style of the `actionButton`, look into [Shiny Themes](http://rstudio.github.io/shinythemes/)

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

ui =(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4, wellPanel(
      sliderInput("numObs", "Number of observations", 1, 30, 3),
      uiOutput("buttons"),
      actionButton("goButton", "Apply Changes")
    )),
    column(8,textOutput("a"))
  ) ))

server = (function(input, output) {

  output$buttons <- renderUI({
    obs <- input$"numObs";
    objs <-list();
    for (i in 1:obs ){
      objs <- list(objs, numericInput(inputId = paste0("t", i), "Day:", NA),br());
    }        
    objs <- fluidRow(objs);
  })

# keep track if the Number of obseervations change
  previous <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    input$numObs
  })

  t <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {

    for(i in 1:input$"numObs"){
      if(i ==1){
        t <- c(as.numeric(input[[paste0("t",i)]])[1]);
      }
      else{
        t <- c(t,as.numeric(input[[paste0("t",i)]])[1]);
      }
    }
    return(t)
  })

  output$a<- renderText({
    if(previous() != input$numObs){
      return()
    }
    paste("number = ", t());
  })
})
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```